# Как настроить компилятор для java в Sublime Text 3?

Tags: java, sublime-text-3

Как настроить компилирование кода java в Sublime text?

```
 class A {

 }

 class B extends A{


 }

class C extends B{
 public static void main(String ...args){
 A a =new B();
}
```

}

Есть вот такой код . Мне надо что бы саблайм скомпилил его и запустил тот класс в котором есть метод мейн . При этом название файла в котором лежит этот код может быть каким угодно . 
Например файл test.java и код выше. Мне надо скомпилить и запустить этот код в саблайме.
Каким образом настроить это ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 2):

В языке Ява имя файла и класса должны совпадать. Это сделано намеренно. Где угодно по другому, в Яве именно так.